# Export Tableau Dashboard to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, import, export, visualization, tableau-api

I was just wondering if there was a way to export my current Dashboard in Tableau to import it into Visual Studio my data is all local and i don't have a server running.

Comment: Do you want to export the tableau data or the dashboard?

Comment: What do you want to to in Visual Studio, if "imported"?